# I'm having problems using @BeanParam annotation

Tags: maven, annotations, jax-rs, pom.xml, wildfly-swarm

I'm using JAX-RS annotations and I'm having problems with @BeanParam. I'm using Wildfly-Swarm and Maven. The next lines are part of my error:

> 2017-05-02 09:57:39,513 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer]
>   (main) deploying e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war 2017-05-02
>   09:57:39,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of
>   "e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war" (runtime-name:
>   "e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war") 2017-05-02 09:57:40,419
>   WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   WFLYSRV0018: Deployment
>   "deployment.e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war" is using a
>   private module ("org.jboss.jts:main") which may be changed or removed
>   in future versions without notice. 2017-05-02 09:57:40,488 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003:
>   Processing weld deployment e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war
>   2017-05-02 09:57:40,561 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final 2017-05-02 09:57:40,861
>   ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001:
>   Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war".INSTALL:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war".INSTALL:
>   WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment
>   "e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war"    at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/example/models/User  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)   at
>   io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:255)     at
>   io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:147)     at
>   io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setScan(BeanConfig.java:172)   at
>   org.wildfly.swarm.swagger.deployment.SwaggerServiceActivator.activate(SwaggerServiceActivator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.service.ServiceActivatorProcessor.deploy(ServiceActivatorProcessor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.test.example.models.User from [Module
>   "deployment.e15735ec-96f3-42f3-be84-4dbd08e05e0d.war:main" from
>   Service Module Loader]    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>     ... 15 more

My pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
<groupId>com.test.example</groupId> 
<artifactId>ws-be-example1</artifactId> 
<name>ws-be-example1</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
<packaging>jar</packaging> 
<properties>
    <version.wildfly.swarm>2016.8.1</version.wildfly.swarm>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>

            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Wildfly Swarm Fractions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ws-be-example1</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>

            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.test.example.Main</mainClass>
                <properties>
                    <swarm.http.port>3001</swarm.http.port> 
                    <swarm.debug.port>5005</swarm.debug.port>
                </properties>

                <environment>
                    <EXAMPLE2_HOST>localhost</EXAMPLE2_HOST>
                    <EXAMPLE2_PORT>8082</EXAMPLE2_PORT>
                    <EXAMPLE2_CONTEXT>/example2/frame</EXAMPLE2_CONTEXT>
                </environment>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My bean:

```
package com.test.example.models;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;

public class User {


   @FormParam("nombre")
   private String nombre;

   @FormParam("apellido1")
   private String apellido1;

   @FormParam("apellido2")
   private String apellido2;

   @FormParam("direccion")
   private String direccion;

public User(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, String direccion) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getApellido1() {
    return apellido1;
}

public String getApellido2() {
    return apellido2;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}
}
```

I'm injecting the before class in my endpoint like this:

```
@Path("/test")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response prueba(@BeanParam User user){
   return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Before all thank for your help :)

Comment: Looks like an issue with integration of swagger.

Can you try removing the WF Swarm `swagger` dependency and see if that fixes the error.

If it does, please raise an issue, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM,  with an example project for us to replicate with

Comment: You need a default constructor in your bean class. This is the only constructor supported. So you will also need setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved ! 
I forgot to add the package of my class in the JAXRSArchive...

```
    JAXRSArchive deployment = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);

    deployment.setContextRoot("example1");
    deployment.addPackage("com.test.example.rest");
    deployment.addPackage("com.test.example.services");

    //I forgot to add this line
    deployment.addPackage("com.test.example.models");
```

Thanks for your help guys ! :)